# MySQL: Returning rows which are matching the conditions: 1. Dates are ascending and 2. Views are descending

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (tab1) which contains id, trending_date and views coulmns. I have to write a query to return those records whose views are decreasing as the trending_dates are going by. E.g. -

```
|ID |Trending_Date | Views |
|---|--------------|-------|
|A  |2021-01-03    |  10   |
|B  |2020-10-30    |   8   |
|A  |2021-02-05    |   9   |
|B  |2020-11-02    |  11   |
```

My intended query will return only the records having "A" as ID. Need help on developing this query...

Thanks,

Amitava

Comment: which mysql version do you have?

Comment: @forpas please clarify a little bit for my understanding.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb4df981495794c5e19cdf34c5b46294 your query returns `A` even though the Views are not decreasing while the days are increasing. Your query checks only the min date and the max date and not any other dates in between. Anyway the OP changed their approved answer so I have to delete my previous comment.

Comment: @forpas got that. Fair judgement. I only considered first and last value to determine the result. But the newly chosen answer just returns same result as mine. That's why I asked what's wrong with mine. And I really liked your thinking and answer. So upvoted it instantly. Never used GROUP_CONCAT like that. Smart thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL 8  you can  use the window function LAG

I added also a version for MySQL 5.x

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `ID` VARCHAR(1),
>   `Trending_Date` VARCHAR(10),
>   `Views` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`ID`, `Trending_Date`, `Views`)
> VALUES
>   ('A', '2021-01-03', '10'),
>   ('B', '2020-10-30', '8'),
>   ('A', '2021-02-05', '9'),
>   ('B', '2020-11-02', '11');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT    ID,`Trending_Date`,`Views`
> FROM
>    (SELECT ID,`Trending_Date`,
>    `Views` ,
>     LAG(`Views`, 1) OVER (
>         PARTITION BY `ID`
>         ORDER BY `Trending_Date`
>     ) lastview
>    FROM tab1) t1
>    WHERE `Views` < lastview
> ```

> ```
> ID | Trending_Date | Views
> :- | :------------ | ----:
> A  | 2021-02-05    |     9
> ```

> ```
> SELECT    ID,`Trending_Date`,`Views`
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> `Trending_Date`,
> IF (@id <> ID,@views := 0,@views := @views) idchange,
> IF (@views >  `Views`,1,0) smaller,
>   @views :=  `Views` as Views,
>   @id := ID as ID
>   FROM tab1,(SELECT @views := 0,@id := '') t1
>   ORDER BY ID,`Trending_Date`) t2
>  WHERE smaller =  1;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Trending_Date | Views
> :- | :------------ | ----:
> A  | 2021-02-05    |     9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c168138f97d5bf6973cbfd6f0a4fbf9a)*

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering my query and resolving my problem. But, this time I come up with a little twist. I need to calculate the % change in views each occurrence of Trending_Date.How would I get the previous record's view count when I am at another current record? I am completely blank! Please help...

Comment: the lag of views is the view from the last day in the list which is save in the column lastview , thsi you can use to calculate. the mysql 6 version you must add to the inner select @views as lastview to achieve the same. My solution is much easier and more understandable the selected

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the `ID`s in the results then aggregate and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT Views)
   AND GROUP_CONCAT(Views ORDER BY Views DESC) = GROUP_CONCAT(Views ORDER BY Trending_Date)
```

`GROUP_CONCAT(Views ORDER BY Views DESC)` sorts the `Views` of each `ID` descending and `GROUP_CONCAT(Views ORDER BY Trending_Date)` sorts the the `Views` of each `ID` by `Trending_Date` ascending.
If the 2 results are the same this means that `Views` are monotonically decreasing.
The condition `COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT Views)` filters out `ID`s with duplicate `Views`.

If you want full rows of the table use the above query with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT Views)
    AND GROUP_CONCAT(Views ORDER BY Views DESC) = GROUP_CONCAT(Views ORDER BY Trending_Date)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e40336583546426c0c0cbd6cc2e0c9e).

Answer (score 0):

I have added two queries. First one with window function for MySQL 8.0 and second one is using subquery for older version of MySQL.

```
 CREATE TABLE tab1 (
   `ID` VARCHAR(1),
   `Trending_Date` VARCHAR(10),
   `Views` INTEGER
 );
 
 INSERT INTO tab1
   (`ID`, `Trending_Date`, `Views`)
 VALUES
   ('A', '2021-01-03', '10'),
   ('B', '2020-10-30', '8'),
   ('A', '2021-02-05', '9'),
   ('B', '2020-11-02', '11');
```

Query#1 (For MySQL 8.0)

```
 select id
 
 from
 (
   select id,trending_date,views,max(trending_date)over(partition by id)maxtdate,
   min(trending_date)over(partition by id)mintdate
   from tab1 
 )t
 group by id
 having max(case when trending_date=maxtdate then views end) < max(case when trending_date=mintdate then views end)
```

Output:

| id |
| --- |
| A |

Query#2 (For older version of MySQL)

```
 select id    
 from
 (
   select id,trending_date,views,(select max(trending_date)from tab1 t2 where t1.id=t2.id)maxtdate,
   (select min(trending_date)from tab1 t2 where t1.id=t2.id)mintdate
   from tab1 t1
 )t
 group by id
 having max(case when trending_date=maxtdate then views end) < max(case when trending_date=mintdate then views end)
```

Output:

| id |
| --- |
| A |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb271f586a6544cc2f2f90eadbbf450b)*

Comment: @Amitava Chowdhury do you need the last row for the ID with descending views? Just asking since you have changed the accepted answer.